# Send password to website safely with Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, authentication

Minecraft uses a launcher on to reduce theft of the game: anyone can download without charge, but the user must provide credentials for a premium account to be able to update the game. I want to build a similar launcher (in Ruby) for a project, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to securely send the password over to an HTTP server (written with Sinatra, if it matters). Obviously, putting it as a parameter in a URL is a really bad idea.

Also, I've though about somehow sending it using password fields, but I don't know how they work (I don't usually do HTTP stuff). This is still a possibility.

Shorter summary: In Ruby, I want to send sensitive info over an HTTP request to a Ruby/Sinatra server.

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: Use HTTPS! It's basically the only way to guarantee safety. It'll also mean that it doesn't matter if it's in a URL, though it might still be logged at the other end if you're not careful, so you should POST it anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Len said, use HTTPS, or, if that is not an option, encrypt just the password with:

- At the very least, XOR encryption
- Maybe DES
- Or RSA (total overkill, unless your game is worth the attention of power hackers to try to break your encryption, as RSA is banking and military grade)

You would then distribute a public RSA key with your launcher, the private on your server, and use those to encrypt the password (or, use those to encrypt the symmetrical encryption key).

Comment: Encryption is ok, but you have to be aware of a possible replay attack. The best way if you're not using HTTPS is to use some form of challenge-respone protocol, or at minmimum embed a timestamp into the encrypted data to mitigate replayability.

Comment: @Casper: I know. I'm no security whiz. But I also believe in simple security for simpler situations. Until you have a game big enough that it attracts the attentions of a hacker good enough to make software that does that for people so they can have the game, simple encryption should be enough. But HTTPS, or another secure protocol is the best way to go. I've been using a little too much raw sockets lately, so I'm forgetting that protocols are usually better.

Comment: Sure. Wasn't meant to shoot down your answer. Just provide the info as potentially good-to-know. Agree on not over-complicating it with regards to game and customer base size.

Comment: @Casper: It was never taken as such. I know that I often sound put-downy and pompous accidentally when I say the normal cleanup things ("We can't help you without the error message", etc.).

Comment: Okay, thanks! I did consider HTTPS, but it costs money to get an SSL certificate, right? I wanted to see if there was a simple _free_ method to do so; I'll probably use it HTTPS sometime in the future. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Jwosty: In that case, you want one of two things: Ship an RSA public key with the launcher and have the private key on your server and use those to encrypt the password, use symmetrical encryption (but the key would ship with the launcher, bad idea), or (maybe) use a protocol like SSH/SSL.

Comment: -1 for the naive advice of 'encrypt the password with ...' which ignores the actual problem: securely exchanging a **key** to encrypt with. Any key exchange protocol would replicate SSL eventually, so just use SSL.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: I answered that in the comments. I'll edit it in.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: See edit, and see if your vote is still applicable.

Comment: @Linuxios: make sure is resilient to a malicious proxy that injects its own public key in the response.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: What are we securing here? Credit card data? Military plans? The code to a safe? We're securing a password transfer for a game. Put things in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Using password fields is no help. Not even when sent over POST. They are sent in plaintext, no matter how hard you try to hide them - that's the very nature of http.

You should definitely use TLS over https instead. The stdlib gives you [Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) for that, but you may use any http client that supports https.

If there is money/value involved in this scheme, don't settle for anything less! Inventing your own protocol is

- way more work (I admit TLS is not always easy to set up, but still a lot less work)
- not secure in 99,9% of the cases
- completely broken in the rest of the cases

No, honestly, inventing secure protocols is probably one of the hardest jobs out there. So be lame and stick to the mainstream (https), it will pay off in the end.

Edit:

You asked whether TLS costs money because of the need for a certificate. That's only an issue on the server side, in one-way authenticated TLS only the server needs to present a certificate, so clients connecting to that server will not have to buy such a certificate. If you operate the server, too, however, then you will need such a certificate. If you don't want to spend the money, you may look into hosting that gives you https for free. [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl) offers such a free service that I know of, and I assume there are other providers as well.

Comment: Alright, you've convinced me that I should use SSL. I'll do that when I actually get it running. Thanks for the response! :)

Comment: @Jwosty: Great! I'm sure it will pay off and not be that much trouble. If it is, come back here for help :)